# Why the newline char does not work here?

Tags: ruby

```
def say(arg)
  "Hello, #{arg}.\n"
end

say("ABC")  # => "Hello, ABC.\n"
```

Why here \n is printed instead of a newline?

Comment: Because `"Hello, ABC.\n"` is a result of call to `say` method. If you want to _print_ the string out, use `puts say("ABC")` (or `puts "Hello, #{arg}.\n"` inside `say` method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `say` returns a String. it doesn't print anything.

If you want to *print* something you should try:

```
def say(arg)
  puts "Hello, #{arg}.\n"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely trying this in `irb` which displays the Ruby representation of a string. Compare:

```
irb(main):007:0> puts say("ABC") + say("ABC")
Hello, ABC.
Hello, ABC.
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> puts "ABC" + "ABC"
ABCABC
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually never printed to stdio or anything like that, you are simply returning a string from a function.

I'll make the assumption that you are evaluating this in IRB, IRB prints out the result of every expression.
use `puts` or similar.